# Perl change column delimiter of a file

Tags: perl

I stored the output of `uniq -c` into two files `$lfile` and `$lfile2`, I tried to make column separator as `" "` with `tr` command, but it seems not working, after split of `$line` there nothing get stored in `$count`, `$e_code`.

How to split the `$line` in two parts?

```
`egrep -o [A-Z]{3}[0-9]{5} $e_file |sort|uniq -c |sort -nrk1 |head -15  >$lfile1`;
`egrep -o [A-Z]{3}[0-9]{5} $y_file |sort|uniq -c |sort -nrk1 |head -150 >$lfile2`;

open (IN, "<$lfile1") ;

foreach $line (<IN>)
{
  my $f_line=`echo $line|tr -s ' ' `  ;
  print "$f_line  \n" ;

  my ($count, $e_code) = split / /, $f_line;
```

Answer (score 0):

`uniq -c` produces output similar to this:

```
      2 ABC12345
      1 ZXC09876
```

Notice the leading spaces. Apparently, you intended to strip the leading spaces but keeping the space in between is vital for `split / /, $f_line;` to succeed.

To remove the leading spaces only use `^\s+` pattern (`^` is the start of line anchor) and pass it to `s///` substitution operator:

```
$line =~ s/^\s+//;
```

---

Please note you may accomplish this task in pure Perl:

```
my %counts = ();
open(my $fh, $e_file) or die "Failed to open $e_file: $!";
while (<$fh>) {
    # collect counts of each [A-Z]{3}[0-9]{5} match in the %counts
    # hash with the match being a kay in this hash and the number
    # of occurrences of this match being the value
    $counts{$1}++ foreach /([A-Z]{3}[0-9]{5})/g;
}

# iterate through the first 15 top encountered matches
foreach my $key (
    (
        sort {$counts{$b} <=> $counts{$a}} keys %counts   # sort dictionary keys
                                                          # in value descending order
    )[0..14]                           # take first 15 items of the ordered list
)
{
    print "$key $counts{$key}\n";
}
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/eN1AyJ